# Why is this NameError Happening?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm Currently Learning Python through Udacity and It gives me a NameError for check_profanity and I'm Unsure Why

```
import urllib


def read_text():
    quotes = open("C:\\Udacity Python\\Lesson 4\\movie_quotes.txt", "r")
    contents = quotes.read()
    print(contents)
    quotes.close()
    check_profanity(contents)


read_text()


def check_profanity(contents_of_file):
    text_to_check = read_text.contents_of_file
    connection = urllib.urlopen(
        "http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="+text_to_check)
    output = connection.read()
    print(output)
    connection.close()


check_profanity()
```

Comment: You're calling `check_profanity()` inside `read_text()` before it was defined. Move the definition of  `check_profanity()` above that of `read_text()`